# Django (Geo) Geocode - geocode on model save not working

Tags: django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, geodjango

I've got this save override on my model:

```
    def save(self, **kwargs):
    if not self.location:
        address = u'%s %s %s %s' % (self.address_first, self.address_second, self.address_third, self.postcode)
        geocoder = Nominatim()
        try:
            _, latlon = geocoder.geocode(address)
        except (GeopyError, ValueError):
            pass
        else:
            latlon = geocoder.geocode(address)
            point = 'POINT({0} {1})'.format(latlon[1][1], latlon[1][0])
            self.location = geos.fromstr(point)
    super(Venue, self).save()
```

I am getting

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

specifically on the address variable. It works fine If I hardcode an address in.

I assume it's something to do with the fact that self.address... is not available until after the model has saved? What's the best way to do this? Save it twice?

Thanks

Updated in case anyone else has an issue. Google is expecting api requests to have the address in such a format Line1+Line2+Line3+Zipcode, rather than Line1, line2, line, zipcode etc etc. So just format the string before you try and geocode. It's not really Django/Python specific.

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    if not self.location:
        address = u'{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(self.address_second, self.address_third, self.postcode)
        address = address.replace(" ", "+").replace(',', '')
        geocoder = GoogleV3()
        try:
            _, latlon = geocoder.geocode(address)
        except (GeopyError, ValueError):
            pass
        else:
            latlon = geocoder.geocode(address)
            point = 'POINT({0} {1})'.format(latlon[1][1], latlon[1][0])
            self.location = geos.fromstr(point)
    super(Venue, self).save()
```

Comment: FFS, everytime I ask a question here I work it out about 30 seconds later...

Comment: In the end, It turns out Google didn't like the address with spaces in, so I had to strip them out and add together each part of the address with a '+'. Question updated for future ref